# chkdsk in cmd is stuck?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, chkdsk

I've encountered a problem with my sd card which I use for my phone, saying it's corrupted (suddenly, haven't had problems before), so I decided to try and salvage it without formatting the card. I've successfully made a backup on my laptop, connected the sd card using an USB adapter and tried running chkdsk over command prompt on my laptop in hopes of fixing the corrupted sd card. However, after using the command "chkdsk G: /f" (G is the sd card), the following was listed out:

```
The type of the file system is exFAT.

Volume Serial Number is 0123-4567

Windows is verifying files and folders...

An error occurred while examining files and directories.
```

It keeps blinking as in it keeps running, however, I've left it like this for nearly 10 hours, and nothing has changed. I'm beginning to think it might be stuck. I want to wait it out, but I'm afraid nothing else will happen but this. On the other hand, I'm afraid of hard resetting the whole laptop (or just restarting the whole thing), or closing the cmd window, or just taking the sd card out so that I wouldn't damage the whole Windows system and possibly have to lose absolutely everything else I have on my laptop. Did I make a mistake by running chkdsk? What should I do now? I haven't found anything else regarding this problem online, so I'm hoping this is fixable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on your laptop is safe. You should, however, have automatic backups set up so you don't have to worry about data loss in situations like this.

The SD card may be dead. If you have a copy of all the files, then try to just format the card. I wouldn't trust it in the long run though. Memory cards are relatively unreliable and this issue could be a sign of its poor condition.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! Is it okay then to just shut the computer down and restart it and take the sd card out or is there another way to stop chkdsk?

Comment: Try Ctrl+C. Alternatively close the command line window